# How to get Google map in ios 6.0 and above versions

Tags: ios

Apple has taken out google map from ios 6.0 version onwards.Apple Using MkMapView that was not that much clear like google map..I used GoogleMapOverlay it displayed the Google map inside the MkMapView..GoogleMapOverlay displays the worldMap i want to move to specific loaction using latitude and longitude...If i specify the latitude and longitude position in GoogleMapOverlay example am getting that particular position alone in rectangle shape overlay at the back i can see my mkmapview...can any one please guide me to resolve this..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Maps on iOS 6 by adding a `UIWebView` and adding Map on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google map sdk for >= ios6

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

```
here is sample code from google sdk ios

#import "YourViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation YourViewController {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

// You don't need to modify the default initWithNibName:bundle: method.

- (void)loadView {
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:24.451794 longitude:54.391412 zoom:12];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.451794,54.391412);
marker.snippet = @"Abu Dhabi";
marker.title = @"Al Jazira Sports and Cultural Club";
marker.map = mapView_;
}


@end
output:
```

[image]

Comment: @Pradeep- I used google map sdk for ios 6.o followed this link only..I can see the google map in my simulator but viewing it in ipad  device the app closes it simply... IPAD DEVICE sdk version - 6.1.3

Comment: can you please paste your code, so that i can check what's the problem

Comment: make sure the ipad device has installed the google map, still the problem exist then download the sdk from https://dl.google.com/geosdk/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.4.2.zip. This zip folder contains the sample code, you can refer and  make your own class or project, and make sure you get the Google API key from https://code.google.com/apis/console/ otherwise your prj will crash

Comment: @Vaishu: i had run the sample code of Google Map in iphone, its working fine here(changed the bundle id which was mentioned while creating the Google API Console)

Comment: I used the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start this link follwed all the steps given here...and generated api with the same bundle id what i used in my project..I can see the google map in simulator working..I don't have device now..let me check whether google map is installed in device or not..After checking that i will confirm you..Thanks for your help

Comment: #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
@implementation ContactUsMapViewController { GMSMapView *mapView_;}
- (void)loadView {GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:24.451794 longitude:54.391412 zoom:12];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.451794,54.391412);
marker.snippet = @"Abu Dhabi";
marker.title = @"Al Jazira Sports and Cultural Club";
marker.map = mapView_;}@end This the code i used.

Comment: In my code i pointed to al jazira sport club.while running in simulator its pointing to that location but the label AL JAZIRA SPORTS CLUB IS NOT SHOWING..https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=Al+Jazira+Sports+and+Cultural+Club+-+Al+Ittihad+-+Abu+Dhabi+-+United+Arab+Emirates&hl=en&ll=24.451794,54.391412&spn=0.003965,0.004823&sll=14.222454,79.557495&sspn=0.540465,0.878906&oq=L+JAZIRA+SPORTS+&+CULTURAL+CLUB&hq=Al+Jazira+Sports+and+Cultural+Club+-&hnear=Al+Ittihad+-+Abu+Dhabi+-+United+Arab+Emirates&t=m&z=18 if u see in this link its showing the label..but in my map its not showing the label.

Comment: i used your code its showing the label as "Al Jazira Sports and Cultural Club"...pls chk in your end

Comment: No i cant able to see in my simulator..I can see Abu Dhabi Fire Brigade label near to my location but not Al jazira sport club...

Comment: just zoom the map you can see Abu Dhabi police GHQ,Abu Dhabi mens collegelike that it should display al jazira sport club.https://maps.google.co.in/mapsq=Al+Jazira+Sports+and+Cultural+Club++Al+Ittihad++Abu+Dhabi++United+Arab+Emirates&hl=en&ll=24.451794,54.391412&spn=0.003965,0.004823&sll=14.222454,79.557495&sspn=0.540465,0.878906&oq=L+JAZIRA+SPORTS+&+CULTURAL+CLUB&hq=Al+Jazira+Sports+and+Cultural+Club+&hnear=Al+Ittihad++Abu+Dhabi++United+Arab+Emirates&t=m&z=18see this link.it will show aljazirasportclub below the marker.dont onclick the marker below the marker it should say aljazirasports club

Comment: @Vaishu: i dont knw wats the pblm in your end, but its shows me the label as mentioned in the above code.